# How to change my code to target a list of display objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
if( listnumber != "listBox1")
    this[listnumber].visible = false;
else
    this[listnumber].visible = true;
```

I would like to change this statement to make the new listnumber visible, and make any other invisible.

Thanks to Baris Usakli for suggesting the mentioned code, my question just needed to be clearer

Comment: If this is related to a previous question; you should add it as a comment to the answer from Baris so that they may edit their response.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeVisible(a:Array,s:String):void{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].name == s)
            a[i].visible = true;
        else
            a[i].visible = false;
    }
}
```

Your question is confusing so I've done the best I can to decipher what you want done. You can call that function from your script passing the array of objects and the string you want tested based on a variable (change the variable "name" to whichever is required) through the parameter. This won't work if there are objects with the same name (or at least it'll turn all objects with that name visible and all others invisible).

Hope it helps.